# at.js the cursor goes always at start of textearea

Tags: jquery

I'am using at.js (version 1.5.1) in a site, but the issue that i encounter is that the cursor goes always at start of textarear when typing something.

I'am using firefox 41.0.1, the code that i'am using is the following :

```
jQuery(item)                
            .atwho({
                at: "@",
                tpl:"<li data-value='${key}'>${name} <img src='${url}' height='20' width='20' /></li>",
                callbacks: {
                    remote_filter: function(query, callback) {
                        if(query.length > 0) {
                            jQuery.getJSON(jQuery( "#user_mentions" ).val(), {q: query}, function(data) {
                                    callback(data.users)
                                });                             

                        }
                    }
                }
        });
```

Do-you have to know what goes wrong ?

Thanks by advance